# flask application timeout with amazon load balancer

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, werkzeug

I'm trying to use a Flask application behind an Amazon Load Balancer and the Flask threads keep timing out. It appears that the load balancer is sending a `Connection: keep-alive` header and this is causing the Flask process to never return (or takes a long time). With gunicorn in front the processes are killed and new ones started. We also tried using uWSGI and simply exposign the Flask app directly (no wrapper). All result in the Flask process just not responding.

I see nothing in the Flask docs which would make it ignore this header. I'm at a loss as to what else I can do with Flask to fix the problem.

*Curl and direct connections to the machine work fine, only those via the load balancer are causing the problem. The load balancer itself doesn't appear to be doing anything wrong and we use it successfully with several other stacks.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I have now is using gunicorn as a wrapper around the flask application. For the `worker_class` I am using `eventlet` with several workers. This combination seems stable and responsive. Gunicorn is also configured for HTTPS.

*I assume it is a defect in Flask that causes the problem and this is an effective workaround.*

Comment: I can't be certain but it just seems like a defect in how Flask is handling an HTTP 1.1 request.

Comment: Did you submit an issue about this at GitHub?

Comment: In your description you state: "With gunicorn in front the processes are killed and new ones started." Then in this answer you say "The solution I have now is using gunicorn as a wrapper around the flask application."

Is it how you "wrap" your WSGI-application that fixes your issue,
or is it that you're now using a different worker type?

Comment: @malthe, both. Using gunicorn alone with other worker classes did not work. Though in a more recent project I think we may have used 'gevent' for compatibility with that library.

Comment: In my experience, simply adding ``-k eventlet`` fixes the issue. I did some debugging on the ``sync`` worker and it seems to hang indefinitely reading from the socket after the response is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to set `session.permanent = True` and `app.permanent_session_lifetime`?

Comment: Sessions are not being used.

Comment: Where do you change this exactly? I am not familiar with these settings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to force all connections is to make sure you are using `HTTP/1.0` and not adding the header `Connection: Keep-Alive` to the response.

Please checkout `werkzeug.http.remove_hop_by_hop_headers()`.

Comment: How and where do you change this exactly? I am not familiar with these settings. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an HTTP load balancer? Using a layer 4 balancer might just as well solve your problem, because it does not interfere with higher protocol levels.